# kivy textinput can't enter text

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I'm currently working on a code where I plot a histogram with matplotlib. I'm using kivy to display. When I run my code I'm able to see the plot, so no problem there. I want to enter the bins manually by using a textbox and a update button. If I enter the text with python (like default: 50), the plot will update itself if I click on the button, but when I want to click on the textbox to enter text, nothing happens. I don't see my cursor in the textbox.

My code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('module://kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy')
from kivy.app import App
import csv


from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2Kivy
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from mpldatacursor import datacursor
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("c:/Users/test.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    data = []
    for column in reader:
        data.append(column[1])

    results = data
    results = [int(i) for i in results]

bins = 200
plt.hist(results, bins=bins, color=[0,0,1])
fig = plt.gcf()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.hist(results, bins=200, edgecolor=[0,0,0,1], alpha = 0.8, color= 'b')
datacursor(ax)

canvas = fig.canvas

def callback(bins):

    global fig, results
    plt.clf()
    bins = int(bins)

    plt.hist(results,bins=bins, color=[0,0,1])
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.hist(results, bins=bins, edgecolor=[0, 0, 0, 1], alpha=0.8, color='b')
    datacursor(ax)

    canvas.draw()

class HistogramApp(App):

    def build(self):
        f = FloatLayout(orientation='vertical')
        g = GridLayout(size_hint=(1,0.05), cols=2)

        self.btn1 = Button(size_hint=(0.5,0.1), pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':0}, text="Update")
        self.textbox = TextInput(text="50", size_hint=(0.5,0.1), pos_hint={'x':0.5, 'y':0})

        self.btn1.bind(on_press=lambda x: callback(self.textbox.text))

        nav1 = NavigationToolbar2Kivy(canvas)

        f.add_widget(canvas)
        f.add_widget(nav1.actionbar)
        f.add_widget(g)
        g.add_widget(self.btn1)
        g.add_widget(self.textbox)

        return f

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HistogramApp().run()
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: 1. can u try typing something into the textinput after clicking and using a button to call a function that can extract the text from that textinput just to make sure at least it working.2 Try changing the color of the cursor

Comment: When I extract the text it is always the default text. Can't change it. I changed the colour of the cursor, but when I click on the textbox nothing happens. So the cursor isn't blinking in the textbox like it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself. My mistake was by using a floatlayout. A better way is using two gridlayouts:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('module://kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy')
from kivy.app import App
import csv

from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2Kivy
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from mpldatacursor import datacursor
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("c:/Users/test.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    data = []
    for column in reader:
        data.append(column[1])

    results = data
    results = [int(i) for i in results]

bins = 200
plt.hist(results, bins=bins, color=[0,0,1])
fig = plt.gcf()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.hist(results, bins=200, edgecolor=[0,0,0,1], alpha = 0.8, color= 'b')
datacursor(ax)

canvas = fig.canvas

def callback(bins):

    global fig, results
    plt.clf()
    bins = int(bins)

    plt.hist(results,bins=bins, color=[0,0,1])
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.hist(results, bins=bins, edgecolor=[0, 0, 0, 1], alpha=0.8, color='b')
    datacursor(ax)

    canvas.draw()

class HistogramApp(App):

    def build(self):
        g1 = GridLayout(orientation="horizontal", rows=3)
        g2 = GridLayout(orientation='horizontal', cols=2, size_hint=(0.05, 0.05))

        self.btn1 = Button(size_hint=(0.5, 0.1), pos_hint={'x': 0, 'y': 0}, text="Update")
        self.tekstvak = TextInput(text="50", size_hint=(0.5, 0.1), pos_hint={'x': 0.5, 'y': 0},cursor_color=[0, 0, 0, 1])

        self.btn1.bind(on_press=lambda x: callback(self.tekstvak.text))

        nav1 = NavigationToolbar2Kivy(canvas)

        g1.add_widget(nav1.actionbar)
        g1.add_widget(canvas)
        g2.add_widget(self.tekstvak)
        g2.add_widget(self.btn1)
        g1.add_widget(g2)


        return g1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HistogramApp().run()
```